# how to convert regular expression of django 1.4 to django 2.0 style path?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

`url('add/(?P<journal_type>C[DR])/$', add_bank_entry),`

how to convert this line to django 2.0 version `path()` pattern? What is does `C[DR]` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `C` is just a literal character that must match. The `[DR]` part is regular expression syntax for *one character, either a `D` or and `R`*. So the following two paths are valid for the given URL pattern:

```
add/CD/
add/CR/
```

and the `journal_entry` will be set to either `'CD'` or `'CR'` when the `add_bank_entry` view is called.

You could either register *two* routes and [pass in default values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options) for `journal_type` for each, use the regular expression as is with `re_path()`, or register a custom path converter that knows how to handle the two string matches.

Using two urls is simple enough:

```
path('add/CD/', add_bank_entry, {'journal_type': 'CD'}, name='add_bank_entry'),
path('add/CR/', add_bank_entry, {'journal_type': 'CR'}, name='add_bank_entry'),
```

This does the exact same thing; match one of two possible URL paths and pass in the right string value for either to the view function.

You can just take the original regex and not convert at all by replacing `url()` with [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions):

```
re_path(r'add/(?P<journal_type>C[DR])/$', add_bank_entry),
```

In Django 2.0, `url()` is an alias for `re_path()`, so you can get away with not changing anything for now. In a future Django release, the alias is going to be removed.

If the pattern is common in your URLs (across different Django apps even), you can create a custom path converter:

```
from django.urls import register_converter, StringConverter

class JournalEntryTypePathConverter(StringConverter)
    regex = 'C[DR]'

register_converter(JournalEntryTypePathConverter, 'journaltype')
```

then use that in a path:

```
path('add/<journaltype:journal_type>/', add_bank_entry),
```

Comment: i can write upto `path('<str:journal_type>/', views.something)`.. and how to write those C[DR]?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: you don't have to, but I'll explain how in a sec.

Comment: sir how to do such in path then ?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: see the updated answer. You have *3 different options* to pick from here, all 3 will work as replacements for your current `url()` definition. Pick one.

Answer (score 1):

From Django documentation for [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#url)

> `url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None)` This function
>   is an alias to `django.urls.re_path()`. It’s likely to be deprecated in
>   a future release.

Key difference between [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) and [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path) is that `path` uses route without regex

You can use `re_path` for complex regex calls and use just `path` for simpler lookups

So, you can use 
**`re_path('add/(?P<journal_type>C[DR])/$', add_bank_entry),`**
instead of

`url('add/(?P<journal_type>C[DR])/$', add_bank_entry),` *if the regex is working fine with `url()`*